# Increase JS Array item while looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I'm working on a graphic code (like a simplified QRcode) made of black and white squares. In the HTML canvas I'm able to detect each square position and pixels. The prob is to count how many black pixels are present in each square area.

Say my code is 5x3 squares. I create an array for each row: `row_1 = [0,0,0,0,0];`

Is a pixel black or white?

```js
for (let i = 0, j = pix.length; i < j; i += 4) {
    if(pix[i+0] + pix[i+1] + pix[i+2] < 30) { /* add 1 to array */ }
}
```

Once the square entirely scanned the array should looks like `row_1 = [20,1580,0,1250,40];` saying that 1st, 3rd and 5th squares are white and 2nd, 4th are black.

Final values should be 0 (white) and 1600 (40x40) but the code captured by a phone cam may not be exactly horizontal/vertical.

I've tried different solutions but none is working:

```js
// first square is [0]
if(pix[i+0] + pix[i+1] + pix[i+2] < 30) { row_1[0] +=1 }
if(pix[i+0] + pix[i+1] + pix[i+2] < 30) { row_1[0] = row_1[0]+1 }
if(pix[i+0] + pix[i+1] + pix[i+2] < 30) { row_1[0].splice(0, 1, row_1[0]+1) }
```

How to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

**** EDIT

My first idea (working well) was to define a var instead of the array `let row_1_1 = 0` then for each black pixel: `if(...black pix...){ row_1_1 +=1 }`
It works perfectly but 1) I have to create manually a lot of vars and 2) using an array I can loop the whole function. Using a var means exploring separately each square with its own var as result. Using an array means it's possible to explore all row squares with only one line of code.

Comment: Why do you create the `j` var on your for loop instead of making the condition `i < pix.length`? and what is `pix`?

Comment: Point of note: row, not raw.

Comment: let imgctx = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, cameraCanvas.width, cameraCanvas.height);
let pix = imgctx.data;

Comment: ooops :-) raw -> row

Answer (score 0):

It works.

```
 let row_1 = [ 0,0,0,0,0 ];

 let imgctx = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, cameraCanvas.width, cameraCanvas.height);
 let pix = imgctx.data;

 for (let i = 0, j = pix.length; i < j; i += 4) {
    if( ... condition to detect the 1st row in canvas... ) {
        for (let c = 0, l = 5; c < l; c ++) { // loop for 5 squares
            if( ...condition for each square: left and width... ) { 
                if(pix[i+0] + pix[i+1] + pix[i+2] < 30) { row_1[c] +=1; }
            }
        }
    }
 }
 alert("1st row = "+row_1) // -> [0,1552,53,1492,112]
```

Then loop the array and `Math.round((1552/1600)*100)` gives the % of black pixels in each square = 97%. Square is black.